# Video doesn't work when program is run from a JAR file

Tags: java, video, netbeans, jar

I use Xuggler, I have used absolute path for the video file, it works perfectly when I run in Netbeans, but when I launch it from jar file, the video doesn't come out.. here the code

```
File file = new File("C:\\qssinfo\\video\\Wildlife.avi");
decodeAndPlayVideo.PlayVideo(file);
```

This is the code of DecodeAndPlayVideo class, (I got it from xuggler and I edited a Little)

```
public class DecodeAndPlayVideo {
private ImageComponent mScreen;
private IStreamCoder videoCoder;
private IContainer container;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public DecodeAndPlayVideo(ImageComponent mScreen) {
    this.mScreen = mScreen;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void PlayVideo(String filename) {
    if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(
        IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version"
            + " of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for "
            + "this demo to work");
    }

    container = IContainer.make();

    if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " + filename);
    }

    int numStreams = container.getNumStreams();
    int videoStreamId = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) {
        IStream stream = container.getStream(i);
        IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();

        if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            videoStreamId = i;
            videoCoder = coder;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (videoStreamId == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("could not find video stream in container: "
            + filename);
    }

    if (videoCoder.open() < 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("could not open video decoder for container: "
            + filename);
    }

    IVideoResampler resampler = null;
    if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) {
        resampler = IVideoResampler.make(videoCoder.getWidth(),
                                        videoCoder.getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24,
                                        videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder.getPixelType());
        if (resampler == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("could not create color space "
                + "resampler for: " + filename);
        }
    }

    IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
    long firstTimestampInStream = Global.NO_PTS;
    long systemClockStartTime = 0;
    while (container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId) {
            IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder.getPixelType(),
                                                    videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight());

            int offset = 0;
            while (offset < packet.getSize()) {
                int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, offset);
                if (bytesDecoded < 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("got error decoding video in: "
                        + filename);
                }
                offset += bytesDecoded;

                if (picture.isComplete()) {
                    IVideoPicture newPic = picture;
                    if (resampler != null) {
                        newPic = IVideoPicture.make(resampler.getOutputPixelFormat(),
                                                    picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
                        if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("could not resample video from: "
                                + filename);
                        }
                    }
                    if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("could not decode video"
                            + " as BGR 24 bit data in: " + filename);
                    }

                    if (firstTimestampInStream == Global.NO_PTS) {
                        firstTimestampInStream = picture.getTimeStamp();
                        systemClockStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {
                        long systemClockCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo =
                            systemClockCurrentTime - systemClockStartTime;
                        long millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo =
                            (picture.getTimeStamp() - firstTimestampInStream) / 1000;
                        final long millisecondsTolerance = 50; // and we give ourselfs 50 ms of tolerance
                        final long millisecondsToSleep =
                                (millisecondsStreamTimeSinceStartOfVideo
                                    - (millisecondsClockTimeSinceStartofVideo
                                    + millisecondsTolerance));
                        if (millisecondsToSleep > 0) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(millisecondsToSleep);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    BufferedImage javaImage = Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic);
                    updateJavaWindow(javaImage);
                }
            }
        } else {
            do {
            } while (false);
        }

    }
    close();
}

private void updateJavaWindow(BufferedImage javaImage) {
    mScreen.setImage(javaImage);
}

public void close() {
    if (videoCoder != null) {
        videoCoder.close();
        videoCoder = null;
    }
    if (container != null) {
        container.close();
        container = null;
    }
}
```

Please can you help me, I got stack for a month X(

Comment: stack? what does "stack for a month" mean? Do you mean "stuck"? And if so, what does that have to do with the Java issue here?

Comment: Also this: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` worries me just a *little* bit!

Comment: Do you see any error messages when you try to run this?

Comment: sorry typo hehehe, when I launch the application from JAR file, the video doesn't preview, can you help me for fix it? I have read some about compiling JAR such as getResourceAsStream etc2, but the file is in the BIN folder, I want to use Absolute file like above example..

Comment: No error message, the video run smootly when i run in netbean.. but when i run form the jar(from CLEAN AND BUILD) in netbean.. the video gone.. that's my problem..

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to debug jar file.. but I have tried debug my application in netbean.. and no problem

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> I have read some about compiling JAR such as getResourceAsStream etc2, but the file is in the BIN folder, I want to use Absolute file like above example..

If your file is in the BIN folder, then it is likely inside of the jar file and *cannot be accessed as a file*. Instead do what should be done by accessing it as a resource relative to the location of the class files, and your code will have a much better chance of working.

As an aside, I'm curious how the file is in the BIN folder when it's path in your code above is `"C:\\qssinfo\\video\\Wildlife.avi"`

**Edit**
Another issue: is your jar file's manifest set up correctly so that the video library jar file that it is dependent on is on its class-path?

For instance, does your jar's manifest file contain the line:

```
Class-Path: xuggle-xuggler.jar
```

or something similar, and is this jar file in the same directory of your jar file (or actually, is it in the user dir)?

Comment: I don't want use relative path, because I want change the source of video file frequently, my file is in here "C:\qssinfo\video\Wildlife.avi" I have try to access C:\example.txt with abosulte path, with scanner Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\example.txt")); and succesful in netbean and jar file too.., but whem I accessed the video file, i onely successful in netbean, not when I launch the jar.. Sorry I'm not good in english.. may be make you confuse abit with my writing

Comment: @Cornelius: then make sure that you're not trying to access something held in the jar file. Make sure that your video file is on disk and that your absolute path to it is correct.

Comment: yes I'm not access a file in jar file.. my file in C:\qssinfo\video\Wildlife.avi, I use absolute file to access it, but it didn't work..
should I give all of my application code in here?

Comment: This in my jar file, http://www.mediafire.com/?4o7xh6lx8mq336a
It is be supposed to run a video file in C:\qssinfo\video\Wildlife.avi, but it doesn't

Comment: The video run when i try in netbeans.. not when i run the Jar file.. :((

Comment: I don't know how to do it through NetBeans, but you could simply extract it out of the jar and then stick it back in after you've edited it. It's a zip file after all, and any zip file utility will allow you to do this. You should leave the other parts of the original manifest file alone, else the JVM won't know which class contains the correct main method.

Comment: Sorry there is it,


Class-Path: lib/xuggle-xuggler-noarch-5.4.jar lib/slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar


should i rename to 

Class-Path: xuggle-xuggler.jar?

Comment: This is my dist folder.. I think, it's correct.. http://www.mediafire.com/?349zgcza71qzvzr
But I confused why the video doesn't run @.@